# No executable found matching command "dotnet-add"

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-core-1.0, fedora-25

I just did a fresh install of Fedora 25 (followed by an install of dotnet core 1.1) to explore the possibilities of doing some dotnet core development in an linux environment. On attempting to add my first package I received the following error:

No executable found matching command "dotnet-add"

I have seen some similar errors in other SO posts, but nothing that seems to be helping this issue. I attached some images below of the error, dotnet version info, system path, and dotnet location.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Thanks ahead of any tips!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have installed a version of the dotnet SDK ("CLI" / `dotnet-dev` package) of the preview2 time, which is still project.json based. This version of the CLI does not contain the `dotnet add` set of verbs. These were publicly released with the `1.0.0` version. (at the time of writing, the current version of the SDK / CLI is `1.0.4`).

Depending on which instructions you followed to install the components,  make sure to update to new versions of the SDK / CLI (e.g. microsoft's [install instructions for Fedora](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core#linuxfedora)).

Note that the version of the SDK / CLI is a different one that the version of the runtime(s) on the machine.

Comment: This is correct - `dotnet add` works fine on my machine with `dotnet --version 1.0.1`.

Comment: I followed the instructions for Fedora 24, but it led me further into the abyss. Now anytime I execute dotnet I get the following: Failed to initialize CoreCLR, HRESULT: 0x80131500

Comment: There are builds on https://copr.fedorainfracloud.org/coprs/nmilosev/dotnet-sig/ but I'm not sure which versions they include. Microsoft support for Fedora 25+ comes with the 2.0 CLI (currently in preview) using the portable `linux-x64` build. Instructions at https://www.microsoft.com/net/core/preview#linuxfedora

Comment: I used the first link (https://copr.fedorainfracloud.org/coprs/nmilosev/dotnet-sig/) to do the original install. At that point I was good to go, with the exception of being able to add packages. Martin's answer addressed that, but then another issue crept up (https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues/4865). I think I will wait and work with 2.0 for FC 25 when it drops and when some of the libraries I am dependent on are updated for 2.0. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

Had the same trouble running VS 2017 Version 15.3.5 found a very helpful article 
http://thedatafarm.com/data-access/no-executable-found-matching-command-dotnet-ef/

My Basic problem is the tooling is split into two:

One for CLI:  Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet

One for Powershell:  Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools

Comment: try answering the question here, rather than linking. If you're asking a further question, try adding a new questions.